# Execute a external program within a groovy script and capture the output

Tags: groovy

I need to write a groovy script, that is executing a external program and print the output of that program to the console.

Here is the regarding code snippet:

```
def pmdCommand = "${scriptDir}/run.sh pmd -d ${filesToAnalyse}"

def sout = new StringBuffer()
def serr = new StringBuffer()

def process = pmdCommand.execute()
process.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
process.waitFor()
if (process.exitValue() !=0 ) {
    System.err << serr.toString()
    System.exit(-1)
} 
else {
    System.out << sout.toString()
    System.exit(0)
}
```

I did something similar in Java, but I can't translate it to groovy.

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
String s = null;

try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    p.waitFor();

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.err.println(s);
    }

    System.exit(0);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Update: I seems the waitFor() never returns and blocks the execution

**Solution provided by Emmanuel Rosa:**

```
def pmdCommand = "/usr/src/app/lib/pmd/bin/run.sh pmd -d ${filesToAnalyse} -f codeclimate -R ${ruleset} -l apex -v 35"

def sout = new StringBuffer()
def serr = new StringBuffer()

def process = pmdCommand.execute()
process.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
process.waitForProcessOutput()

System.out << sout.toString()
System.exit(0)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your groovy version of the code?

Comment: @tim_yates I updated my groovy code above and It seems the waitFor() method never returns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#consumeProcessOutput(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) states that `consumeProcessOutput()`...

> Gets the output and error streams from a process and reads them to
>   keep the process from blocking due to a full output buffer. The
>   processed stream data is appended to the supplied OutputStream. For
>   this, two Threads are started, so this method will return immediately.

So far so good. Here's the important part...

> The threads will not be join()ed, even if waitFor() is called.

And the solution...

> To wait
>   for the output to be fully consumed call waitForProcessOutput().

So what you can do is replace `process.waitFor()` with `process.waitForProcessOutput()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was not the only problem, but definitely a part of the issue.