# Read serialized data from subprocess call to python script in groovy

Tags: python, groovy

I have a groovy code in which a python script is invoked. Is there a way to read the json serialized data printed/returned by the python script?

**Groovy code to call python script:**

```
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
def cmd = ["python2.7","myscript.py"]
def proc = cmd.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitFor()
def parser = new JsonSlurper()
def jsonResp = parser.parseText(sout[0])
log.debug(jsonResp)
```

**Python script:**

```
dd = {'key1': 'value1', 
      'key2':'value2', 
      'key3': {'key31':'value31'}
      }
print json.dumps(dd)
```

**Output:**

`jsonResp = {}` when the code is run.

`jsonResp['key1']` also is empty implying that json is not read from process output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799111/unable-to-capture-full-output-from-groovy-execute/50799554#50799554

Comment: have u got any error in above code ? or are u looking for another method ?

Comment: @Uchiha_Itachi the value of jsonResp = {}. The serialized json is not getting read correctly. I am not sure if print json.dumps(dd) is the right way to pass data back to groovy script.

Comment: have you got the output?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for this:

- `print json.drumps(dd)` from the python code works well and completed its work. you have to read the process output inside the groovy code correctly.

In groovy script, `def jsonResp = parser.parseText(sout[0])` you are using `java.lang.StringBuilder` as `Array list`. This will act like `String []`. So you are loading first character `"{"` of your string `sout[0]`in total String.

> I don't know why you put it like this.

`JsonSlurper().parseText` only allows the `String` argument See [doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html). You can use it like below shown ways:

- `parseText(sout.toString())`
- `parseText(sout.readLines())`